# How to update date in vue2-datepicker

Tags: vue.js, datepicker

I'm using the Vue2-datepicker package, inserting a data works well but how can a date be updated

```
      <template>
<div>
        <div v-for="shop in shops" :key="shop.id">
          <date-picker v-model="shop.start_date" valueType="format"></date-picker>
    <button @click="preparePayload">Update</button>
        </div>
</div>
        </template>
        export default {
          components: {
            DatePicker
          },
            data: function() {
            return  {
            start_date:''
        };
                  },
              methods: {
                  preparePayload() {
                  var form = document.getElementById('shop');
                  var payload = new FormData(form);
                  payload.append('start_date', this.start_date);
                  this.updateShop(payload);
                  .....
                 }
            },
            };
            </script>
```

It always comes back null

Comment: Could you please show the code for your data properties and where you try to see the date?

Comment: if defines `valueType="format"`, you may have to add props=`format` like `<date-picker v-model="shop.start_date" valueType="format" format="YYYY-MM-DD"></date-picker>` then `shop.start_date` has to be one string the format is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: @Jakub i've edited the question, thanks.

Comment: @Sphinx, i don't think so, i think the problem is with the vmodel though, the package does not accept :name prop or :value prop so it makes it harder

Comment: @Jakub already pointed out the root cause after your provided full code. But I think `vue-datepicker` will throw out some warnings because of defines `valueType="format"` but no `props=format`  or `start_date` is not one string matches the format.

Comment: @Sphinx, looking at the documentation it might just go ahead without warning. It seems to the be basic use-case such as: `<date-picker v-model="time1" valueType="format"></date-picker>` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-datepicker). Eventually the OP could initially assing `start_date` to `null` value, as per documentation.

Comment: `null` should be ok from the guide. but I remembered I met some warnings before when used `valueType="format"` in `vue2-datepicker`. Probably the author already improved something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in this case, your button is within the `v-for`, then you could try passing the value of date directly to the function:

Let's say your data looks like this:

```
data() {
    return {
      shops: [{ start_date: null }, { start_date: null }, { start_date: null }],
    }
}
```

then in your HTML template:

```
<div v-for="(shop, index) in shops" :key="index">
    <date-picker v-model="shop.start_date" valueType="format"></date-picker>
    <button @click="preparePayload(shop.start_date)">Update</button>
</div>
```

then in your method:

```
methods: {
  preparePayload(date) {
    console.log(date)
  }
}
```

You can see something similar in action [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-feather-ylh69?file=/src/App.vue).

---

In case if you wanted to achieve the reactivity then you could do the following:

Add additional data property:

```
data() {
    return {
      shops: [{ start_date: null }, { start_date: null }, { start_date: null }],
      myDates: {}
    }
}
```

then in your HTML template, you would additionally pass the `index` with `click` event to be able to create unique key-value pairs within our `myDates` object:

```
<button @click="preparePayload(item.start_date, index)">Update</button>
```

finally, in your method you could use [$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects):

```
preparePayload(date, index) {
   this.$set(this.myDates, `newDate${index}`, date);
}
```

You can see how that would work [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue?file=/src/App.vue).

Comment: shop.start_date is actually dynamic data, say from a v-for.

Comment: It would be ideal if you could provide a reproducible code in this case as this poses different issues. You could use https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Comment: I've edited the question @jakub, the date field is gotten from a v-for, if i click on the update button without choosing a new date, i believe the old value should be passed but no, it passes null values, could this be due to two way binding?

Comment: @LDUBBS, thanks for providing more information. I also updated the answer and tried to recreate something similar. Hopefully, it will give you some ideas.

Comment: All good, glad it helped. Sorry, I do not have twitter.